# Count the results of an equation

Tags: crystal-reports

When I try the following equation in Crystal Reports 10, I am told the field `{@Total less one}` cannot be summarized:

```
if {@Total minus one} = 1 then count({@Total minus one}) else 0
```

I need to count the number of times `{@Total minus one}` is equal to `1`, `2`, `3`, and so on. This shows how many jobs in the month have had 1 change, how many have had 2 changes, etc.

My equation `{@Total minus one}` is

```
{#Count of changes} -1
```

and my RT `{#Count of changes}` is simply a count of field occurrences, resetting on the group of Job Number. How can I create this formula?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't summarize a summary. `Total Minus One` is a count, you can't get a count of a count.

Try rewriting your logic to use Shared Variables instead.

Comment: I have alter the @Total minus one to be Whileprintingrecords;
Global numbervar C1:=c1+1

Comment: Unfortunately Not. I still get the 'This field cannot be summarised'

Comment: Try using shared variables to replace *any* use of summaries. Just make a variable that increments by one whenever it meets your condition.